# Tilde or accent on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, character-encoding

I have this piece of code to make a consult:

```
text = 'pestañas'
text.split(' ').each do |word|
    @dictionary = Dictionary.where('spanish_word LIKE ?', "%#{word}%").first
end
```

But if I see on the debugger, I have this consult:

```
Dictionary Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `dictionaries`.* FROM `dictionaries` WHERE (spanish_word LIKE '%pestaas%') LIMIT 1
```

I have this problem with ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú  or latin characters. My MySQL DB encoding is UTF-8 Unicode (utf8), Ruby 1.9.2p0

Comment: Can the code find it in the console? I have an app which is UTF8 and has an autocomplete. I pasted in the word, checked the output, and it was including the tilde just fine in the query. Lets see if the console helps narrow down where the problem is occuring

Comment: yes, I tested in the console but the result is the same -> Dictionary Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `dictionaries`.* FROM `dictionaries` WHERE (spanish_word LIKE '%pestaas%') LIMIT 1 The method is declared in a helper, can this causing the problem??

Comment: I just tried this in a rails/mysql app ruby1.9.2p290:


`>> Dictionary.where("title like ?", "%pestañas%")`
`Dictionary Load (0.2ms)  SELECT dictionaries.* FROM dictionaries WHERE (title like '%pestañas%')`


Works like expected. Are you sure, your database AND Table AND column is utf_general or utf_general_ci?

Do you have in your application.rb `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

There is also some options internal/external encoding for ActiveRecord...

Comment: Don't you have to have the "magic comment" (#encoding: utf-8) on the first line of the file to use 'ñ'? Do you have that?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But I still with the same problem.
@stwienert, my ruby version is 1.9.2p180 and the database encoding is utf_general_ci
**VotaVader**, I tried that too, but nothing, it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Which MySQL gem are you using? You should use the ruby-mysql or the mysql2 gem.

See [Reads for Rubyists](http://www.rvdh.de/2010/04/03/pro-tip-using-mysql-with-rails-3-0-0-beta2-and-ruby-1-9-2/) for more info.

Comment: I'm using the mysql2 0.2.7 gem